# Find special number in String using regEx

Tags: java, regex

I'am having diffuculties with regular Expr. I must find 123 in string `String str = "abc.123,a"`. I tried 
`if(str1.matches("[\\s,.!]*123[\\s,.!]*"))
            System.out.println("String " + str1 +" consist number " + searchNumber);`
But it doesn't work, but if i have `String str = .123,` it works.

Comment: What do you mean you must find it? You need the index? You need to just know whether it exists?

Comment: Try this: `str1.matches(".*[\\s,.!]123[\\s,.!].*")`

Comment: @nhouser9 i must find it and sent messege to user if it exist in String

Comment: @Andreas Thank you very much! It works

Comment: why can't you use str1.contains("123")

Comment: @ravthiru Because that would find `1234` too, and OP wants number surrounded by spaces, `,`, `.`, or `!`.

Comment: @ravthiru because i can have String str = abc123,321. But i must find bare number(without letter near).

Comment: @Andreas i'am so sorry, but can you tell me what does dot means in regEx? I can't understand

Comment: @Vladislav It is one of the most common regex special characters. If you don't know that one, then you haven't even *tried* to learn regex, and StackOverflow is not a teaching site. Search the web and you'll find lots of excellent regex guides.

Comment: All you need is to use `Matcher#find()` with your regex. Besides, you might be interested in a word boundary - `"\\b123\\b"`. See [this demo](http://ideone.com/2M9j8Q). Word boundaries match before/after letters, digits and underscores (so, if you need to match `_123_` you would need a special boundary pattern).

Comment: @Andreas ok, thank you!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'll test it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used `Matcher#find()` with your regex, you would get a match because `find()` searches for partial matches.  However, since `[\s,.!]*` matches *0* or more occurrences, your pattern does not meet your *i must find bare number(without letter near)* requirement.

You might be interested in a [**word boundary**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) based solution - [`"\\b123\\b"`](https://regex101.com/r/tE2TCZ/2). See [this demo](http://ideone.com/2M9j8Q). Word boundaries match positions before/after letters, digits and underscores.

If you really need to match `123` that is NOT between letters, use

```
String pat = "(?<!\\p{L})123(?!\\p{L})";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tE2TCZ/1), where

- `(?<!\p{L})` - ([negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)) asserts that there is no letter before
- `123` - `123`
- `(?!\p{L})` - ([negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)) asserts there is no letter after `123`.

*However*, that will find `123` in `01234`, so I believe a word boundary regex is the right solution for you.

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/1TnF7V):

```
String str = "abc.123,a";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\p{L})123(?!\\p{L})");
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(str);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("YES");
}
```